# Android - TextView height issue according to content (text)

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout whose layout_height is set to "wrap_content" and inside that I have a TextView whose text is set at runtime. I have set android:layout_height="wrap_content" to my TextView, but it doesn't seems to change the height of the Textview even if the content is larger than 1 line.

It only takes the height of single line and displays 1 line, and all the remaining lines appears to be marquee vertically which is seen when I drag it manually...

So plz anyone can help me out.

Comment: could you paste your code -- xml and any related java code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - TextView dynamic height issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609698/android-textview-dynamic-height-issue)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/someId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:layout_weight="1"    
/>
```

Comment: I think you are using --> to point at the important values. But that makes your example invalid xml...