# Android - TextView dynamic height issue

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout whose layout_height is set to "wrap_content" and inside that I have a TextView whose **text** is set at **runtime**. I have set android:layout_height="wrap_content" to my TextView, but it doesn't seems to change the height of the Textview even if the content is larger than 1 line.

It only takes the height of single line and displays 1 line, and all the remaining lines appears to be marquee vertically which is seen when I drag it manually...

so what will be the issue?

Comment: Can you post your layout and code? There's just not enough detail in your description to do anything but guess wildly without seeing the actual setup.

Answer (score 1):

change property of textview Input Type:textMultiline

You can use also this

```
textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml("Titleeee"));
```

here i found a list of text that fromHtml will convert

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html